# Example for non-rectifiable set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

The definition of rectifiable set is that if the constant function $1$ is integrable over the set $S$, then the set $S$ is rectifiable. What can be an example for non-rectifiable sets? I cannot visualize it.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant constant function, sorry :)

Comment: No problem, that makes more sense!

Comment: No unbounded set is rectifiable.

Comment: @AndresCaicedo Are there not unbounded sets with finite measure? By this definition they would be rectifiable.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes, of course. I meant to write "interval" rather than "set".

Comment: The word rectifiable actually doesn't mean what you say it does...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an example of a non-rectifiable curve, we may take any [space-filling curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve), i.e. a continuous surjective map $[0,1]\to [0,1]\times [0,1]$. This is indeed difficult to visualize and was one of those things that 19th century mathematicians were upset to discover existed. In the language given [in this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifiable_set), $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ is not a $1$-rectifiable set.

Comment: I don't think the notion of a rectifiable *curve* can be connected with the OP's definition of a rectifiable *set*.  In particular the Question asks about illustrating (im)possibility of integrating a constant function on a set $S$, so you would need to demonstrate how $S$ arises from your space-filling curve to fill out the Answer.

Comment: @hardmath it at least satisfies this definition: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifiable_set The OP's definition is a set with finite measure.